# What is Chrome doing when "Confirming card"?

Tags: google-chrome

When you auto-fill a credit-card in Chrome it gives you a little spinner and says "Confirming card".

What is chrome doing when confirming your card?

<s>(I have the distinct feeling it's one of those artificial, fake delays, in which case - **CAN I DISABLE IT? HOW?** Didn't see anything in `chrome://flags`)</s> Guess not. See answer.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually Chrome doing it and not the website?  As a test use a brand new Chrome user profile and confirm the behavior still happens.

Comment: Look at the Credit Card site for your account. Vendors and CC companies have worked out a zero value transaction to test the card is good. I see that. This is what may be happening. This happens online when you enter the card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what I could find in the Chromium source code:

When Chrome shows you only the last four digits of your card number (e.g. "Visa ‪•⁠ ⁠•⁠ ⁠•⁠ ⁠•⁠ ⁠9874"), it doesn't actually *know* the rest of the card number – it has to "unmask" the autofill entry by requesting from the Google Pay servers.

This is why Chrome asks you to enter the CVC before autofilling – the code is sent to the Pay servers as part of the "unmask" request, the CVC is *actually verified* by Google Pay, and only then your browser receives full card number back.

From the long delay, I am guessing that the CVC is verified against the card issuer (because Google is forbidden from storing it on their own servers). Indeed my bank actually shows Google placing a $0.00 hold (which is a standard procedure for card verification) immediately after using the autofill function.

- https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/autofill/core/browser/data_model/credit_card.h;l=40;drc=53cb2b1669bd3363c7e87d199ccb2ca979ebfd1d
- https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/autofill/core/browser/payments/full_card_request.h?q=OnFullCardRequestFailed&ss=chromium
- https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/autofill/core/browser/payments/full_card_request.cc;l=69?q=FullCardRequest&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc

Comment: I encountered the 0.00 hold. I can't properly parse the chromium code, but this answer seems correct. Thanks.

Comment: That’s not exactly true, it is different to have a card in GPay and just having it in Chrome Payment Methods Autofill. Until a few months, I could always autofill credit card numbers with just a simple click. Now Chrome always wants a CVC confirmation before it fills the number into the form, but only for those card(s) that are also in GPay. (Using Google Chrome on Linux.)